# SQL efficiency join on two fields or one

Tags: mysql, sql, join, relational-database

Let say that I have got three tables: account, contact and address. To account and contact I want to assign multiple addresses. Is it better to have two fields in address `join_type` and `join_id` and then for example running query:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM address a
INNER JOIN contact c ON c.id = a.join_id AND a.join_type = 'CONTACT';
```

and

```
SELECT a.*
FROM address a
INNER JOIN account ac ON ac.id = a.join_id AND a.join_type = 'ACCOUNT';
```

or have `account_id` and `contact_id` instead of `join_type` and `join_id` and running query:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM address a
INNER JOIN contact c ON c.id = a.contact_id;
```

and

```
SELECT a.*
FROM address a
INNER JOIN account ac ON ac.id = a.account_id;
```

or maybe even have got two seperate address tables for account and contact? The first option is the best for future if I would like e.g. have also addresses assigned to users.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT a.*
FROM address a
INNER JOIN contact c ON c.id = a.contact_id;

The fact that you have multiple types of addresses should not cause any problem since the contact_id should always be unique.

I would also consider having another column in address with account_id and have another join like this:

SELECT a.*
FROM address a
INNER JOIN account a ON a.id = a.account_id;

Comment: of course contact_id would be unique, but let say that I have got mln records in address table and I need to add extra field e.g. user_id, then it would take about 5 minutes to add this new field, that is why I was thinking about doing it more dynamic by `join_type` and `join_id`, but this would not happen so often, so maybe you are right

Comment: It's always nice to think ahead but it's also important no to over design.. thank you for accepting my answer.